# RDD Memory footprint in spark

Tags: apache-spark, compression, rdd, parquet, memory-footprint

I'm not sure on the concept of memory foot print. When loading a parquet file of eg. 1GB and creating RDDs out of it in Spark, What would be the memory food print for each RDD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create an RDD out of a parquet file, nothing will be loaded/executed until you run an action (e.g., first, collect) on the RDD.

Now your memory footprint will most likely vary over time. Say you have 100 partitions and they are equally-sized (10 MB each). Say you are running on a cluster with 20 cores, then at any point in time you only need to have `10MB x 20 = 200MB` data in memory.

To add on top of this, given that Java objects tend to take more space, it's not easy to say exactly how much space your 1GB file will take in the JVM Heap (assuming you load the entire file). It could me 2x or it can be more.

One trick you can do to test this is force your RDD to be cached. You can then check in the Spark UI under Storage and see how much space that RDD took to cache.

Comment: Thanks for the response marios. When you mention partitions is it the RDDs created out of the parquet file? And as RDDs are not physical entities there would only be data in-memory based on the action we perform, Am I understanding it right? Also could there unequal partitions as well?

Comment: All RDDs are partitioned, otherwise there is no parallelism. You are right, RDDs are not materialized until they need to (they are lazy). If is one large parquet file, it should be quite equally partitioned. Yes, there are cases where partitions are impalaced, especially when the RDD is generated from many smaller files instead of one large one.

Answer (score 1):

Marios, in your memory projection you didn't take into account the compression of Parquet. 1Gb could very well be 5GB uncompressed.