# Optimized caching via spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I am working on a solution to provide low latency results using spark. For this, I was planning to cache the data beforehand on which a user wants to query.

I am able to achieve good performance on the queries. One thing I noticed is that the data on cluster (parquet format) explodes when caching. I understand this is due to deserializing and decoding the data. I am just wondering if there is any other options to reduce the memory footprint.

I tried using

```
sqlContext.cacheTable("table_name")  and also
tbl.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
```

But nothing is helping reduce the memory footprint

Comment: This cached data is not permanent for users to.query ...it's time/memory bound within the spark context  
  .. why can't you consider other options like mem sql  or memcache or hive query based on partirions

Comment: I know it is not permanent. We expect the users to run some queries on the same dataset, hence wanted to cache the data till the user is there. We do want to explore other options, but for now we will be using spark for low latency.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to try orc ?  There have been improvements in orc support recently (more here: https://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/orc-improvement-in-apache-spark-23-95295487).   I am not an expert, but I heard that orc uses in memory columnar format...  This format gives opportunities for doing things like compressing via techniques like run length encoding  of repeated values -- which tends to lower memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

It also explodes when not caching.

cache has nothing do with reducing memory footprint. You do not state RDD or DF, but I presume latter. This [RDD Memory footprint in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060245/rdd-memory-footprint-in-spark) gives an idea for RDDs and the improvements for DFs / DSs: https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/deep_dive_into_storage_formats.html.

You cannot reuse the data for different users. What you could consider is Apache Ignite. See https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/spark/shared-memory-layer.html